# Set first level items to <h5> in wp_nav_menu()

Tags: menus

```
<div class="news-features">
           <h5><a href="">News & Features</a></h5>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="">Industry News</a></li>
                ............
            </uL>
</div>
```

First Menu need h5 tag then others menu need ul li tage.

Comment: can you explain? how would your HTML look like? you want all main items to have `<H5>`?

Comment: yes, all main items <H5>

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to extend the *Walker* class.

See [/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php) for reference.

Comment: I solve this problem wp_nav_menu() + uses jQuery according to my requirement.following -->> <?php wp_nav_menu(
                                   array(
                                       'menu' => 'fot-both',
                                       'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
                                       container => false
                                      )
                                     ); ?>                            and use jQuery.....wrap().

Comment: @asraful While it's good you found a solution to your problem, using javascript to alter simple output is a very unclean solution.

A custom walker would be the clean way to handle this.